# Add onclick="return false;" on checkboxes if click on link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to add "onclick=return false;" on my checkboxes after when a click is made on a link.
And if user click on submit button, then "onclick=return false;" should be removed.

Is there a way to add onclick="return false;" on input by document.getElementById?
I have tried multiple options to implement this... But none works, I am going crazy...

My code:

```
    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1">1 option<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2">2 option<br>
    <a id="link-next" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript: void(0)">Next</a>
    <button id="button-filter">Filter</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why not disable the checkbox instead, that's less frustrating for the user. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wmajfnd6/

Comment: Cause disabling, I'm not able to pass on form the value contained on input.

Comment: Before disabling, you could capture the values in a hidden input.

Comment: @mykaf maybe a work around solution. Is it necessary a js code to made that?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use JS to disable on the fly and capture those values. Maybe a better question is: why do you need to disable the checkboxes after a link is clicked? Assuming the link opens a new tab/window.

Comment: I'd like to disable checkboxes for correct usability of my form. Anyway a found a different work around, adding and removing .style.pointerEvents = "none" on div that contains checkboxes